# Drupal 6 : Not able to fetch group_id(gid) from OG table

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-6

I am creating nodes pro-grammatically by fetching emails. Where I am splitting the subject of the mail for creating it for specific group & the title of the node.
Now I want to fetch the group_id by the description of the group and wrote query for it, but it's not working. Let me paste the code here..

```
list($group_name, $title_text) = explode(', ', $title);
$query = "SELECT * FROM {og} WHERE og_description = ' ".$group_name." ' ";
$group_details = db_query($query); 
while ($group = db_fetch_object($group_details)) {              
   $gid = $group->nid;
}
echo $gid;
```

`echo $gid` is giving nothing. Though `$group_name = 'Logo design'` & `gid = 1442` for it in table.
Is there anything I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. Here is the answer:-

```
$title = "ED's presentation, This content is for ed's presenation"; //This is the subject of the mail, which I am fetching.

list($group_name, $title_text) = explode(', ', $title);
$query = "SELECT nid FROM {og} WHERE og_description = '".$group_name."'";
$group_details = db_query($query);
while ($group = db_fetch_object($group_details)) {
{
  $gid = $group->nid;
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following two pages , the examples give here does not use the single quotes around the placeholder in the query  ($group_name - in your example) .

http://drupal.org/node/310072

One of the lines says "**Note that placeholders should not be escaped or quoted regardless of their type**" .

http://drupal.org/node/1407528